# How to restore data to postgresql database after adding column?

Tags: database, postgresql, psql, restore, dump

I have a postgresql database for code (flask, ember) that is being developed.  I did a `db_dump` to back up the existing data.  Then I added a column in the code.  I have to create the database again so the new column will be in the database.  When I try to restore the data with `psql -d dbname -f dumpfile` I get many errors such as 'relation "xx" already exists', " violates foreign key constraint", etc.

I'm new to this.  Is there a way to restore old data to a new empty database that has all the relationships set up already?  Or do I have add a column "by hand" to the database when I add a column in the code, to keep the data?

Answer (score 1):

When you did the `pg_dump`, you only dumped the data and table structure, bit did not drop any tables.  Now, you are trying to restore the dump, and that will attempt to re-create the tables.

You have a couple options (the first is what I'd recommend):
Add `--clean` to your `pg_dump` command -- this will `DROP` all the tables when you go to restore the dump file.

You can also `--data-only` your `pg_dump` command -- this will only dump the existing data, and will not attempt to re-create the tables.  However, you will have to find a way to truncate your tables (or delete the data out of them) so as not to encounter any FK errors or PK collisions.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to proceed is to use `ALTER TABLE` to add a column to the table.

When you upgrade code, you can simply replace the old code with new one. Not so with a database, because it holds state. You will have to provide SQL statements that modify the existing database so that it changes to the desired new state.

To keep this manageable, use specialized software like Flyway or Liquibase.